# How to add Background image for Custom UIToolBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

i am using below code to add background image to the Custom UItoolbar where it has 4 Custom UIBarButton it in.I want to add background image for the ToolBar i searched many things and tried but nothing is working. can anyone please tell me how to add background image for Custome UIToolBar for the Frame which i have specified.

```
UIToolBar *toolBar =[[UIToolBar alloc]init];


-(void)layoutSubviews{

 CGRect frame;
  frame = CGRectMake(20 ,90, 150, 30);
    toolBar.frame = frame;
UIImage* toolbarImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar_background.png"];
[[UIToolbar appearance] 
    setBackgroundImage: toolbarImage 
    forToolbarPosition: UIToolbarPositionAny
    barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

The Above code is not working For me as mine is Custom Toolbar adding progrmatically and also i am adding it as per requirment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now, it is working fine. You can try it, if its works fine,
1.First i set the tool bar hidden to NO.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO  animated:YES];
```

2.addin Image to UItoolbar
     UIImage *toolbarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_BottomBar1.png"] 
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

```
[[UIToolbar appearance]setBackgroundImage:toolbarImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

1. i added the bar Button to it.
   UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"My Place" 
   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(clickedButton1)];

   NSArray *itemsN = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button0,button1,button2, nil];
   [self setToolbarItems:itemsN animated:NO];

Try this, Hopefully it will works..